# ajax - view different content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mime-types

I want to listen to music or watch video in the same page (without opening a new page in browser). So I want to use ajax for this purpose. I have different files and I want to do something with them depends on it's type. For example, I have `1.mp3` - listen, `2.avi` - watch, `3.png` - view. I need to have the same behaviour like if I click on href. `<a href="http://server.com/3.png" target="blank"></a>` - It opens new page and loads `3.png`.
Please, help me! Thanks.

Comment: It depends on method you're planning to use for playing video and audio files. Generally, you even don't need ajax for that, you can load dynamic content using `iframe` tag and usual links.

Comment: Riateche, I like your answer, but could you tell me more about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<div id="contentdiv" style="display:none">
<iframe id="contentframe"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').click(function(){
   var hreflink = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#contentframe').attr('src',hreflink);
   $('#contentdiv').show();
   return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It looks perfect, but I doubt that it starts downloading chosen file, not playing. I use `iframe` to download files. I'll try it of course tommorow. Thanks.

Comment: If it isn't loaded, just call `$('#contentframe').load();`

Answer (score 0):

create individual classes for your contents as:

```
<a href="http://server.com/1.png" target="blank" class='png'></a>
<a href="http://server.com/2.avi" target="blank" class='avi'></a>
<a href="http://server.com/3.mp3" target="blank" class='mp3'></a>

Now code in individual classes as

$('.png').click(function(){
 alert('png');
});
$('.avi').click(function(){
 alert('png');
});
$('.mp3').click(function(){
 alert('mp3');
});
```

**OR**

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var ext=$(this).attr('href').val().substring($(this).attr('href').val().lastIndexOf('.')+1).toLowerCase();
   if(ext=='png'){
     //code for png
   } //and so on
})
```

Comment: I presented only 3 types, but in real life there are many types.